# Python3 how is mro defined in object?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Update------------------

`object` is a instance of `type`, but at the same time, `object` is also the base class of `type`. And `type` is a instance of `object`. I'm really confused about this. it's totally unlogical. Why python do this?

```
>>> isinstance(object,type)
True
>>> isinstance(type,object)
True
>>> type.__bases__
(<class 'object'>,)
```

Original--------------------------------

I know `type` has `mro`. but I can't figure out why `mro` can be called from `object`. How python implement this?

```
>>> object.mro()
[<class 'object'>]
>>> 'mro' in dir(object)
False
>>> 'mro' in object.__dict__
False
>>> 'mro' in dir(type)
True
>>> 'mro' in type.__dict__
True
>>> issubclass(type,object)
True
```

Comment: Because class attributes can always be accessed from an instance.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams thanks but still confusing

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams That's not the whole story, `type.mro != object.mro`.

Comment: @tcpiper You should probably post your update as a separate question if you want people to see and answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#invoking-descriptors) are involved.

When resolving `object.mro`, the interpreter first looks for `'mro'` in `object.__dict__`.

```
>>> object.__dict__['mro']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'mro'
```

Since `'mro'` is not in `object.__dict__`, the interpreter looks in `type(object).__dict__`.

```
>>> type(object).__dict__['mro']
<method 'mro' of 'type' objects>
```

This object is a descriptor since it has a `__get__` method.  So the interpreter invokes the `__get__` method to obtain the actual value of `object.mro`.

Based on the documentation you might think that since `object` is a class it would call `__get__(None, object)` but in this case `object` is being considered as an instance of class `type` so the interpreter calls `__get__(object, type(object))` to get the result.

```
>>> type(object).__dict__['mro'].__get__(object, type(object))
<built-in method mro of type object at 0x1047d2ae0>
```

To confirm that the result is what we're looking for:

```
>>> type(object).__dict__['mro'].__get__(object, type(object)) == object.mro
True
>>> type(object).__dict__['mro'].__get__(object, type(object))()
[<class 'object'>]
```